# Android Layout TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

How can i fit this text view so it doesn't deform the 2 Image Buttons.I would like to have it on top of them 2.
This is how they appear now:

[Layout now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7pG1.png)

[This is how the buttons should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DEVk.png)

Here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="horizontal">



<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/botoAbdominals"
    android:background="@drawable/abdominals"
    android:contentDescription="ImatgeAbdominals"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/botoFlexio"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/flexio"
    android:contentDescription="ImatgeFlexio"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Escull la rutina desitjada" />
```

Comment: put the textview outside of your linearlayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this, with this layout arrangement:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Escull la rutina desitjada" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/botoAbdominals"
        android:background="@drawable/abdominals"
        android:contentDescription="ImatgeAbdominals"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/botoFlexio"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flexio"
        android:contentDescription="ImatgeFlexio"/>

   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

put another `LinearLayout` around it, that is vertical orientation. With the textview and Linearlayout as children to it.

The following hierarchy.

```
> LinearLayout (vertical)
  > TextView
  > LinearLayout (horizontal) // [Like your current one]
    > ImageButton
    > ImageButton
```

Comment: @AlexiaWhite Glad to hear it. And that you managed it yourself without me posting full code :)